# Value of optional type [PFObject] could not be unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift

Just upgraded to xCode 7.2 and Swift 2 and am getting the following error message in my function. Can anybody help me out? Could be something really simple but I cant seem to figure it out. The corrections in xCode did not help any and I have tried unwrapping everything in the if let posts = posts line and still nothing.

> Value of optional type '[PFObject]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to
>   use '!' or '?'?

```
func refresh() {
    var postsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    postsArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    postsQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    postsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) -> Void in
        if let posts = posts as [PFObject] {
            self.postsArray = posts
            self.table.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add a question mark `posts as? [PFObject]` for optional binding.

Comment: Then I get this error: `Downcast from '[PFObject]?' to '[PFObject]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?`

Comment: Then the compiler knows the optional return type and you can completely omit the casting `if let unwrappedPosts = posts {` (it's confusing to use the same name for the optional and unwrapped optional)